# Parse many small strings or a single big string - which is faster?

Tags: regex, performance

In a scenario where a large number of strings must be parsed with regular expressions, considering the same RegEx needle will be used for all tests, which would be faster:

1. To test each string in an array, individually, or;
2. To concatenate everything into a single big string and test just once?

I believed number 2 would be best instead of having to fire up the RegEx engine multiple times for processing an array of strings. However, after some testing in PHP (PCRE), it seemed untrue.

## Benchmark

---

I've made a simple benchmark in PHP 5.3 [(source code)](http://pastebin.com/znW5jYY9) and got the following results:

> **122185** interactions in 5 seconds testing multiple smaller strings inside an array
>
> **26853** interactions  in 5 seconds doing the single big-string test

Therefore, I must conclude the first method is up to 5 times faster. However, I'd like to ask for an authoritative answer confirming this; I could be assuming things mistakenly due to some PHP optimization I'm unaware of.

Is it always a more optimized solution to fragment large strings before testing them with regular expressions, not specifically in PCRE?

### preg_grep()

I don't think this function should be considered here. It's a benchmark test, not an optimization issue. Not to mention that function is a PHP-specific method. Also, `preg_match_all` returns all matched substrings whereas `preg_grep` just indicates which array elements matched.

Comment: regexes have to be compiled. unless you're writing some hideously ugly long regex, the compile overhead is where your time diff is coming from.

Comment: @MarcB I don't understand. Compiling overhead should be bigger when I call the RegEx function for each string in my array than in the second method, yet it's 5 times faster.

Comment: ah. sorry. read your results backwards, thinking they were time-equivalents (e.g. 26853 shorter than 122185). However, if you're dealing with an array, then don't use preg_match in a loop. there's preg_grep for dealing with matching in arrays. Perhaps it's concatenation overhead killing performance now. Try pre-building the monolithic string, THEN do the tests.

Comment: The issue could be memory. Allocating a huge amount of space for the super-string could slow your system down, but I'm not sure how big the string is or how you're actually loading the strings in either situation.

Comment: If you have interest I've provided the source code in my post - http://pastebin.com/znW5jYY9 It's very unlikely the benchmark has overloaded my computer at all. Also I made sure I had a fairly optimized code.
Parsing multiple strings really is faster than a big one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your benchmark is flawed. Look at this piece of your code:

```
while(time() - $TimeStart < 5)
    for($i = 0; $i < $Length; $i++, $Iterations++)
    {
        preg_match_all($RegEx, $Input[$i], $m);
    }
}
```

The `$Iterations` should *only* be increased in the `while`, not inside the `for`. Dividing the former results results in:

```
24437 iterations using array
26853 iterations using big string
```

You shouldn't use `time()` for time measurements, `microtime()` would be more suitable to gain accuracy.

Lastly, this benchmark isn't complete, because to obtain the same results for both tests, the array method needs to perform `array_merge()` after every iteration. Also, somewhere a big string needs be transformed into an array and that takes time too.

Comment: That's weird... In my eyes my code does basically the same as yours. Looking side by side I can't really tell anything essentially different. http://pastebin.com/uQ0kS6G3 (adapted) I still get the array method many times faster than imploded string method.

Comment: @caiosm1005 the results with pcre tend to slow down on bigger strings, that might explain a few things. Nonetheless, the grep option is probably the best to use at this point.

Comment: But it's the same string as in your code. Why are the results opposite?

Comment: @caiosm1005 It's not the same code still ... check my updated answer.

Comment: Oops! You're right, my mistake ;) I'll update my answer later

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should **not** merge all the target strings into one.  For one thing, it will break a lot of regex that work okay on the shorter strings. Anchors like `^` and `$`, `\A` and `\z`, would suddenly find themselves with nothing to match.  Also, regexes that rely heavily on things like `.* or`.*?`, which work on shorter strings despite their inherent inefficiency, would tend to become [catastrophically](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) slow when used on the Frankenstring.

But even if the concatenated version turned out to be faster, would it matter?  Have you tried the array version and found it to be too slow?  This is a pretty drastic solution (if solution it is); I'd hold off on implementing it until I had a problem it could solve, if I were you.